# Aggregating Event Exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, events, listener, aggregateexception

I'm following on with a tutorial detailing handling events thrown in multiple subscribers to an event. However when the code is run, the `TargetInvocationException` catch block isn't catching the exceptions thrown in the method body of the subscribers: `throw new Exception("Hello")` and `throw new Exception("World")` respectively.

Instead I get an unhandled exception error in the first listener, predictably at `throw new Exception("Hello")` in `private static void AlarmListener`.

What is it that I'm doing incorrectly when attempting to catch the invoked method's exceptions?

```
class AggregatingExceptions
{              
    public void Main()
    {
        //create the alarm
        AlarmAndLocation alarm = new AlarmAndLocation();

        //subscribe the listeners 
        alarm.OnAlarmRaised += AlarmListener;
        alarm.OnAlarmRaised += AlarmListener2;

        try
        {
            alarm.RaiseAlarm("Kitchen");
        }
        catch (AggregateException agg)
        {
            foreach (Exception ex in agg.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void AlarmListener(object sender, AlarmEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Alarm listener 1 called.");
        throw new Exception("Hello");
    }
    private static void AlarmListener2(object sender, AlarmEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Alarm listener 2 called.");
        throw new Exception("World");
    }

}

public class AlarmAndLocation
{
   public event EventHandler<AlarmEventArgs> OnAlarmRaised = delegate { };

   public List<Exception> exceptionList = new List<Exception>();

    public void RaiseAlarm(string location)
    {            
        foreach (Delegate handler in OnAlarmRaised.GetInvocationList())
        {
            try
            {
                handler.DynamicInvoke(this, new AlarmEventArgs(location));
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException ex) 
            {
                exceptionList.Add(ex.InnerException);
            }
        }

        if(exceptionList.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new AggregateException(exceptionList);
        }
    }
}

public class AlarmEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string  Location { get; set; }

    public AlarmEventArgs(string location)
    {
        Location = location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but `AggregateException` is used only in TPL

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I could accept if that were the case but I'd expect the `TargetInvocationException` catch block to still trigger within `RaiseAlarm` before exhibiting unexpected behaviour. As it stands, it doesn't reach any `AggregateException` references as it fails in the dynamic invocation.